# help me with typecasting problem 

Tags: c#

I would like to create a function which can take two arguments object and type and then type cast the object to appropriate type using the type parameter. Is that possible ? how can i achieve it ?

```
public class TEST
{
    public int test;
}
object ot = new TEST();
Type type = typeof(TEST);
TEST t = (type)ot;

//Function will be something like this Type t is type we get using typeof() 
public string SearializeObject(Object obj, Type t)
{
    //check if obj is of type t
    if(obj is of type t){
    //cast obj to type t to read it
    ((Type t)obj).someMethod
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public T cast<T>(object obj)
{
   return (T)obj;
}

object ot = new TEST();
TEST t = cast<TEST>(ot);
```

Comment: @Anil Namde this method in this example is known as `Generic Methods` if you wish to do further reading.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Generic method for this:

```
public string SerializeObject<T>(object obj)
{
  if(obj is T)
    (obj as T).someMethod();
}
```